# (running forever) Finding a triangular # with over 500 factors

Tags: ruby

I am currently working on the peuler question. I think I have the correct code since I tested it with the one that was provided in the example. However, when I try to run it to find the first triangular number with over 500 factors, it stays running for over 15 minutes. But when I try and find the first triangular number with over 100 factors, it finds it in under a minute.

Please see below:

My question is how can I get this too calculate quicker? Because it seems to be stuck?

```
#Project 12 #http://projecteuler.net/problem=12

def triangle(x) #finds the (x)st triangular number
    x=(1..x)
    return x.inject(:+)
end

def factors(x) #calculates how many factors (x) has
    factors =[]
    range=(1..x)
    range.each {|num|
    if x%num==0 
        factors << num
    end
    }
    return factors.length
    end 

def project12(x) #finds the first triangular number that has over (x) factors
i=1
    until factors(triangle(i)) > x
        i += 1
    end
return triangle(i)
end

print project12(500)
```

Comment: Did you try let it running for at least 15 days or 15 months of CPU time? Your code has probably some combinatorial explosion. Did you consider doing some math to lower that!

Comment: This is related to algorithm design and analysis. Your solution is definitely not scalable.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how I can make this program run quicker. I think perhaps I should change the factor definition by seeing if I can square root the number first since that would cut down on the processing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, in triangle(x), you do `x-1` additions. You run through this at `i` and up to `i` in your code, so we have `(i-1) + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + ... + i - 1) which approximates to i^2/2`. Then, in factors your code runs essentially at `x` time. You do this for every `triangle(i)`, so we have `1*triangle(1) + 2*triangle(2) + 3*triangle(3) + 4*triangle(4) + ... + i*triangle(i) = 1*0 + 2*1 + 3*2 + 4*3 + ... + i*(i-1), which is approximately i^3/3 - i/3`.

What does this mean? It means that based on my sketch your program runs at approximately `i^3/3 - i/3 + (i-1)` iterations. This is cubic time and definitely does not scale.

If, for example we had to do this up until `i = 50`, this would run 41699 times through. Now, let us imagine doing it just one time more: 44255 times if `i = 51`. That's definitely not going to scale.

Comment: For example, you're clearly summing numbers from 1 to x in your triangle function. Have you considered using the formula `x(x+1)/2` instead of running at linear time?

Comment: Further, you only use the factors array for counting, so why have a factors array? Might as well just use a counter. A further naive optimization could be knowing what not to check. For example, if we're dealing with 28, do we really need to check whether or not 27 is a factor of it?

Comment: You could instead turn this question into "Could I find the prime factorization of a number, given that number? If I can, I will, through some constant-time mathematical manipulation arrive at the number of factors."

Comment: Also, note that the constant-time mathematical manipulation that I speak of is taking the powers of all your primes in your prime factorization, then adding 1 to each of them, then multiplying that together. For example: `18 = 2^1 * 3^2`. So, 18 has `(1+1) * (2+1) = 6` factors, namely `1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18`.